# ipad to windows quotation issue in pycharm

Tags: windows, macos, ipad

i am using my ipad to connect to my windows laptop through teamviwer to code on my windows laptop. now the issue I am having is that the quotation marks now simply don't work like when I press my quotation mark key on my keyboard it does not get recognized by Pycharm. I am coding Python, and the issue is not allowing me to use quotation marks (the marks appearing on the screen are not accepted by phycharm). And yes I have tried to keymap macos on pycharm and it did not work. any solutions?